# Values not showing up in c:foreach loop

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList iterator to a JSP from a Spring class, but the values aren't showing up when I use a c:foreach loop.  Can anyone help?  Here is the important part of my Spring class.

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorldController implements Controller {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Return View");
        ArrayList<RandomNumber> random = new ArrayList<RandomNumber>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            RandomNumber number = new RandomNumber();
            number.setNumber((int) Math.random() * 100);
            random.add(number);
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("helloworld.jsp");
        Model model = (Model) modelAndView.getModel();
        model.addAllAttributes(random);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my JSP.

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="random" items="${random}">
<tr><td>${random.number}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, but perhaps you should be doing a `model.addAttribute("random", random)` instead or something before returning the `ModelAndView`? You should at least definitely not set the `Iterator`, but just the whole `Collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the line:

```
model.addAllAttributes(random);
```

to:

```
model.addObject("randoms", random);
```

You now have a "randoms" attribute in the context (adding the 's' to the name to resolve another issue I believe with the var naming). Then change the jsp to be (note `random` for the var name avoids overlap with `randoms` the collection):

```
<c:forEach var="random" items="${randoms}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think my main problem is that I basically just have the JSP, the Spring controller class and the RandomNumber class, and I'm trying to run the JSP class directly without running the controller class.  I've tested, and it appears the ArrayList isn't being created, which leads me to believe that nothing is running in the controller to begin with.  I think I've got some basic Spring to brush up on, which I will do and then come back here if I have any other problems.  Thanks to everyone for their kind help.